# CSS3 style an element depending on the state of an input checkbox

Tags: css, css-selectors

What is the meaning of '~' in this example? I saw this example from this tutorial. http://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/

I know it can be used to style an element completely differently depending on the state of that checkbox. However, I can't find any CSS documentation that explains '~'?

```
input[type=checkbox] {
   position: absolute;
   top: -9999px;
   left: -9999px;
   /* For mobile, it's typically better to position checkbox on top of clickable
      area and turn opacity to 0 instead. */
}

/* Default State */
div {
   background: green;
   width: 400px;
   height: 100px;
   line-height: 100px;
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
}

/* Toggled State */
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ div {
   background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a selector for sibling elements. The one you have there will find all of the 'div' siblings of a checked checkbox within the same parent, but only ones that follow the checkbox in the dom. 'Div' siblings preceding the checkbox will not be included.

Awesome selectors reference, including the tilde: 
http://learn.shayhowe.com/advanced-html-css/complex-selectors

Answer (score 3):

It is a general sibling combinator and similar to Adjacent sibling combinator (+). The difference is that the second selector does NOT have to immediately follow the first one means It will select all elements that is preceded by the former selector.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#general-sibling-combinators

> ## 8.3.2. General sibling combinator
>
> The general sibling combinator is made of the "tilde" (U+007E, ~) character that separates two sequences of simple selectors. The elements represented by the two sequences share the same parent in the document tree and the element represented by the first sequence precedes (not necessarily immediately) the element represented by the second one.
>
> Example:
>
> h1 ~ pre
> represents a pre element following an h1. It is a correct and valid, but partial, description of:

```
<h1>Definition of the function a</h1>
<p>Function a(x) has to be applied to all figures in the table.</p>
<pre>function a(x) = 12x/13.5</pre>
```